# Guava Cacheloader from scratch

Tags: java, caching, guava, ehcache

so I need to store some information and reload it from my DB every 1 hour. I looked around and found that **googles guava cacheloader** or **ehcache** would be the best and most simple solution.

I searched google for the past 4 hours and didn't find anyhting that could help me, I am a real newbie, first time I need to cache something. Please help me out.

Follwoing issue:

I have an entity called **News** where I obisouly store news and load them depending on their availibilty. I do this im **@ViewScoped** bean. However, I dont need to load the news every time the page is loaded, the News won't be modified that freqeuntly. This is why I want to store the **News(List < News>)** in the cache and load them respectively. The cache should be refreshed every 1 hour.

Please help me regarding the bean, the cache listener etc. I have really no clue how to reload the data, do I have to use the bean etc.

This is my **@ViewScoped NewsController**:

```
@ViewScoped
public class NewsController extends BaseController implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

private List<News> newsList;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    getAvailableNews();
}

public void getAvailableNews() {
    if (newsList == null) {
        info("#############Load news from DB!##########");
        newsList = new LinkedList<News>();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<News> result = (List<News>) em.createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM news WHERE sysdate BETWEEN from AND to+1",
                News.class).getResultList();
        for (News n : result) {
            newsList.add(n);
        }
    }
}

public void reload(){
    newsList = null;
    getAvailableNews();
}

public List<News> getNewsList() {
    return newsList;
}

public void setNewsList(List<News> newsList) {
    this.newsList = newsList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at EhCache spring annotations (http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/spring-annotations)? Seems like that's exactly what you need here...

Simply add @Cacheable(name="getAvailableNews") above your getAvailableNews() method, and the framework will automatically take care of caching the results for you (first time calls the DB, fetches the results back, and cache them...next time, get it from the cache directly)

For this to work though, you need to change a bit your class construct...I would remove the "newsList" instance variable...that's cause for inconsistencies and troubles...(you probably did that to build some sort of home grown "caching" which I can understand) and update your getAvailableNews() method to actually return the List object...

```
@Cacheable(name="getAvailableNews")
public List<News> getAvailableNews() {
    info("#############Load news from DB!##########");
    return (List<News>) em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM news WHERE sysdate BETWEEN from AND to+1",
            News.class).getResultList();
}
```

Finally, with EhCache, you can set time expirations on cached entries...hence for your case, it might be as easy as setting up the TimeToLive value to 1 hour for the news items...after one hour, the call to the DB will be made again...and you'll fetch the new "news" values...

Comment: @Ianimall Thanks for the response. Where do I set the timer?

Comment: @Ianimall I alos don't use Spring, but EJB.

Comment: ha EJB...in that case i would use ehcache on the client side, basically encapsulating the EJB call into a getAvailableNewsCached() client method...Basic concept: fetch from cache first...if null result from cache, fetch from the EJB and store in cache. For the timer, it's all setup in ehcache.xml. Check out http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/configuration for details about ehcache configurations. Also, getting started guide is good: http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/getting-started and